# Get "humanized" date in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to get the humanized date in Django REST framework for an Android app to consume it.

My class is:

```
class Nota(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    descripcion = models.TextField()as')
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def FORMAT(self):

        return naturaltime(self.fecha)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

And my serialize is:

```
class NotaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    usuario = serializers.Field(source='usuario.username')
    fecha = serializers.Field(source='FORMAT')
    class Meta:
        model = Nota
        fields = ('usuario','subseccion','titulo','descripcion','imagen',
                            'fecha','longitud','latitud','imagen','likes', 'privacidad', )
```

But I get

> "fecha": "1\u00a0day, 18\u00a0hours ago"

I want to get 1 day, 18 hours ago. How can I get the correct format?

Comment: [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) is 'NO-BREAK SPACE'. This problem may or may not be related to [ticket 21415](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21415), *Unicode escapes appear verbatim in translated naturaltime strings* and/or [ticket 20246](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20246), *Use non-breakable space between amount and units*.

Comment: What [version of Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131947) are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
   def FORMAT(self):
       from django.utils.timesince import timesince
       return timesince(self.fecha)
```

Comment: why the funtion is all caps? does it relate to specific convention?